# EF Core with GroupBy - column ambiguously defined

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Trying to filter and group by an IQueryable I get an oracle exception "column ambiguously defined".

The code looks as follows:

```cs
public class UserRepository{
    public IEnumerable<UserDto> GetUsers(UserFilter filter){
        IQueryable<User> users = _context.Users;
        return filter.Set(users)
            .Select(user => new UserDto(){
                Id = user.Id,
                NoOfTweets = user.NoOfTweets
            }
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}

public class UserFilter : Filter{
    public string? Name {get; set;}
    public UserGroupBy? GroupBy{get; set;} //Enum

    public override IQueryable<Model> Set(IQueryable<Model> models){
        IQueryable<User> users = models.Cast<User>();
        users = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)
            ? users.Where(user => user.Name.Equals(Name))
            : users;
        if(GroupBy.HasValue)
        {
             users = GroupBy.Value switch{
                 UserGroupBy.Name => users
                      .GroupBy(user => new{
                           user.Name,
                           user.Birthday
                      })
                      .Select(group => new User(){
                          Name = group.Key.Name,
                          NoOfTweets = group.Sum(e => e.NoOfTweets)
                      })
                 _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
             }
        }      
        return base.Set(users); // in base class the list gets paginated
    }
}
```

I guess the error is because of the two selects (in group-by and finally into userGet) but how can I workaround that cleanly?
I hoped that the entity Framework solves this using aliases, but it doesn't.

My Versions:

- Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore: 6.21.61
- .Net 6

### Additional Thoughts

- Doing the Group by after the paginate leads to an incorrect result because the wrong list gets paginated.
- It seems that the second Select reexecutes the first on so that the `group.Sum(...)` is called twice

Comment: Leaving aside whether "generic repository" is useful or not, use [ToQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring) to see what gets executed. And keep in mind that DbContext is already a multi-entity repository, DbSet is a single-entity repository and LINQ is supposed to make it easier to write queries. Is this code simple to read or write? Does `UserFilter` do what it says, or is it trying to act both as a `Where` and a `GroupBy` ?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about EF Core, but - as far as Oracle is concerned & based on what you said so far, there are (at least) two positions that might raise the error. I'll try to illustrate it on a simple query which selects sum of salaries per each department.

Asterisk points to position which raised the error:

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal)
  2  from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno
  3  group by deptno;
group by deptno
         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

OK, so let's add table name - in vain, it still doesn't work because column in `select` column list also misses its source table name:

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal)
  2  from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno
  3  group by dept.deptno;
select deptno, sum(sal)
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Finally, when fixed:

```
SQL> select dept.deptno, sum(sal)
  2  from emp join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno
  3  group by dept.deptno;

    DEPTNO   SUM(SAL)
---------- ----------
        30       9400
        20      10875
        10       8750

SQL>
```

---

As I said: I can't interpret code you wrote and don't see anything like what I posted, but I hope that these examples might help you find the culprit.

Comment: I know EF *very* well and I can't interpret this code. This is an attempt to implement  "best practices" that converted a LINQ query that would be little different from SQL to something that can't be deciphered without running the code to see the actual SQL.